# Why is my dog sleeping in my bed (previously she was trained to not get on the bed)?

Tags: dogs, behavior, training

My dogs know better to not be on my bed because they pee on it. I have trained them to pee in their pee pads and they already know to do so.
For the past two night, my female dog, Lexi, tends to jump on while I am sleeping and falls to sleep right next to me.

Her and her puppies bed is right next to mine and they each have their own big bed. She jumps on my bed and when I tell her to get off she refuses. When I try to carry her off, she pushes herself back and jumps on top of me like she doesn't want to get off.

Is she trying to tell me something or is she sick or is there something wrong. I have a boy named Sniper that lays down on my bed once in a while but sleeps with my parents on their bed. I try to show all equality to them so why is she acting up now. She was never likes this before. She has always liked her own space next to my bed.